# Unable to display citations using "plainnat" style

Tags: natbib

I noticed that it my document I get a "?" where the citation should be when using

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

However, the numbers appear when I use

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

I have a preamble.tex file from a template which contains the following code related to bibliography

```
% *****************************************************************************
% *************************** Bibliography  and References ********************

%\usepackage{cleveref} %Referencing without need to explicitly state fig /table

% Add `custombib' in the document class option to use this section
\ifsetBib % True, Bibliography option is chosen in class options
\else % If custom bibliography style chosen then load bibstyle here

   %\RequirePackage[square, sort, numbers, authoryear]{natbib} % CustomBib
   \RequirePackage[round]{natbib} % CustomBib

% If you would like to use biblatex for your reference management, as opposed to the default     `natbibpackage` pass the option `custombib` in the document class. Comment out the previous     line to make sure you don't load the natbib package. Uncomment the following lines and spec    ify the location of references.bib file

% \RequirePackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp, citestyle=numeric, sorting=nty, natbib=    true]{biblatex}
% \bibliography{References/references} %Location of references.bib only for biblatex

\fi
```

I tried both including and not including "custombib" in the documentclass options but it didn't make a difference. My main file report.tex contains

```
\input{preamble}
```

to use preamble.tex. And then the bibliography is called as follows:

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % use this to have URLs listed in References
\cleardoublepage
\bibliography{References/references} % Path to your References.bib file
```

I also made sure to delete the .aux, .bib, etc. (all the intermediate) files before recompiling.

I am using vim-latex with the default compilation sequence to generate the PDF.

Any thoughts on why the citations aren't showing up? Thanks!

Comment: Did you run `bibtex` and then ran LaTeX again?

Comment: Yes, because the numbers do appear when I use \bibliographystyle{apalike}. Plus, vim-latex automatically runs the compilation sequence 2 or 3 times by default.